# Accessing images which requires authentication in HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to access images locally in an HTML file from a build server which requires authentication. Below is the example code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Build Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<img width="30%" src="https://ci-system.net/project/build/build-1/image-1.png"/>
<img width="30%" src="https://ci-system.net/project/build/build-1/image-2.png"/>

</body>
</html>
```

I have already signed in to the server in the same browser session. When I open the HTML file in the same browser session, each image tag is trying to authenticate again with the authentication server and these requests are successful without entering the credentials again. In the below image, I have highlighted the two requests for two images.

[image]

But when I enter the URL of the image in the browser directly, it does not require re-authentication, I assume it is because of Session Cookies from the build server.

Why are not the session cookies from the Build server reused when I access these images from the HTML file directly and try to reauthenticate for each image separately?

Comment: Because GET requests does not add any additional headers. You should add login token into image URL or use some API for it

Comment: @Justinas Can you post this as an answer so that i can accept it :)

Comment: What browser are you using? What version of that browser? How is it currently configured with regards to third party cookies?

Comment: @Quentin I am using Firefox 103.0.1 version and regarding cookies option "Cross-site tracking cookies, and isolate other cross-site cookies" is enabled. When i change this to only "Cross-site tracking cookies" it reuses the existing session cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've configured your browser to "isolate other cross-site cookies" so, when you open the HTML document on a different origin, it uses a different cookie jar which does not contain your logged in session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Because GET requests does not add any additional headers. You should add login token into image URL or use some API for it

Comment: Plenty of "additional headers" are added in a GET request. Both the request triggered by the `<img>` and the request triggered by the user "enter the URL of the image in the browser directly" will be GET requests.